# R terra and `Error in x@ptr$geometry(nlyrs) : could not find valid method`

Tags: raster, r, sf, terra

i am using `terra::raster 0.9-1` and, specifically `terra::values` and the xyz function in `terra::rast`, but i keep encountering the following

`Error in x@ptr$geometry(nlyrs) : could not find valid method`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
other attached packages:
 [1] terra_0.9-1       gdalUtils_2.0.3.2 geosphere_1.5-10  data.table_1.13.0 ggplot2_3.3.2     dplyr_1.0.2      
 [9] rgdal_1.5-16      rgeos_0.5-3       stringr_1.4.0     raster_3.3-13     sp_1.4-4          devtools_2.3.1

# dummy XYZ data
m_xyz <- as.matrix(expand.grid(seq(0.5,999.5,1),seq(0.5,999.5,1)))
m_xyz <- cbind(m_xyz, sample(1:10,1000^2,replace=T))

# coerce to rast (used to be raster::rasterfromXYZ)
rast(m_xyz,type="xyz")
Error in x@ptr$geometry(nlyrs) : could not find valid method
```

ok, ignore that and just create a rast and try to populate

```
rBNG <- rast(xmin = 0, xmax = 1000, ymin = 0, ymax = 1000, resolution = 1, crs = "epsg:27700", vals = NA)

# add some values
values(rBNG) <- sample(1:10,ncell(rBNG), replace = T)
Error in x@ptr$geometry(nlyrs) : could not find valid method

rBNG[] <- sample(1:10,ncell(rBNG), replace = T)
Error in x@ptr$geometry(nlyrs) : could not find valid method
```

i am new to `terra`, i have moved to `sf` and `stars` and now `terra` is the next step, perhaps there's just something simple i am not understanding

```
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.5-16, (SVN revision 1050)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-2
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.

Attaching package: ‘rgdal’

The following object is masked from ‘package:terra’:

    project

Warning message:
package ‘sp’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

Comment: You should revert to the CRAN version as it is currently "stable" and the GitHub version is failing in its build. This is why it is not always desirable to use the development version. To revert, you can just open a fresh R session and use `install.packages("terra")`.

Comment: thank you, the stable version does indeed work.

Comment: you were out of luck. The github version had this bug for about 12 hours...